# How to access Azure web site's database

Tags: azure-web-app-service

I created a Wordpress web site in Azure. Is there anyway to access the database that was set up along with it?  (so I can back / or if I should want to Migrate in the future )

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you go to the website dashboard tab, you will see a link call "view connection string". If you click that you will see the connection string with database and server name, user name, and password , etc. You should be able to use those to log into your MySql database using tool such as http://dev.mysql.com/downloads/gui-tools/5.0.html

Comment: WebMatrix 2 also has the possibility to connect with existing MySQL and SQL Server databases and you can also use it to open a deployed website on WAWS and change it accordingly. It's a great tool.